# R raw dataset dcumentation with Rd2pdf

Tags: r, package, dataset, documentation

How to include raw dataset documentation in my R-package?

I can use `R CMD Rd2pdf` to create a pdf that documents my codes, and I would like to include the dataset documentation files (also in my `R/` directory) for raw data files only in the `isnt/` directory

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

Comment: @r2evans, please be more specific about where in that notebook lies the answer.

Comment: There are chapters on *Object Documentation* and *Data*, both relevant. One note is that I think you should not put non- `.R` files in the `./R/` directory, instead rely on the other directories and process for including pdf documents in the package. If you've done your docs right (either manual `.Rd` files or via `roxygen2` comments), then data docs will be included in the results from `Rd2pdf`.

Comment: @r2evans, Yes - I have read those sections. As recommended by those docs, my dataset is documented in a `data.R` file in the `./R` directory and my functions are documented in a `functions.R` file in the `./R` directory. However, only the functions are roxygenized to the `./man` directory.

Comment: The main issue is trying to document raw data files -- I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: `./inst/` isn't really meant for raw data files, but it depends on what you intend for them. For instance, from one perspective, "raw" data means data that is not intended to be deployed with the final package, perhaps used to form the actual data; this is a squishy definition, as many packages ship with CSV files in addition to the `.rda` complements. Is this in a public repo that we can look at?